# Flipping words around a bit?

Tags: sentence-construction

In this headline I came across:

> "We look back at conversations with some of the survivors of the 2018 Parkland school shooting."

would that be acceptable rewriting:

> "We look back at conversations with some of the survivors of the Parkland school shooting, 2018."

Answer (score 4):

No, you would have to say *...the Parkland school shooting in 2018* or *of 2018.*

When we put a date before the name of an incident, it acts like an adjective and doesn't need a preposition, but if the date follows, it does need one.

Comment: seemed so comprehensive with a comma. And neat

Comment: @Lynerapintcho  Could you just use a comma in your native language?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but seems odd.  The usual place for dates when they are part of names is at the start. For example:

> "The 2012 London Olympics" or "The 1945 General Election".

I suppose sometimes you might have a parenthetical date "In the London Olympics (2012) ..." which might be set off with commas  "In the London Olympics, 2012, ..."

But it seems a bit ugly in your example.  Like the date is just floating around not really connected to anything.